# Class.newInstance breaks compile-time exception checking

Tags: java, builder

The following text is from "Effective Java", Item 2:

> The traditional Abstract Factory implementation in Java has been the 
>   `Class` object, with the `newInstance` method playing the part of the 
>   build method. This usage is fraught with problems. The `newInstance` 
>   method always attempts to invoke the class’s parameterless 
>   constructor, which may not even exist. You don’t get a compile-time 
>   error if the class has no accessible parameterless constructor. 
>   Instead, the client code must cope with `InstantiationException` or 
>   `IllegalAccessException` at runtime, which is ugly and inconvenient. 
>   Also, the `newInstance` method propagates any exceptions thrown by the 
>   parameterless constructor, even though `newInstance` lacks the 
>   corresponding `throws` clauses. In other words, `Class.newInstance` breaks
>   compile-time exception checking. The Builder interface, shown above, 
>   corrects these deficiencies.

Please go to [this link](https://gist.github.com/kpgalligan/143fd33011c402c38e95) for full text.

I've been able to follow everything before, "In other words..". Can someone please explain how does `newInstance` break compile-time exception checking and how does Builder pattern fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

'newInstance' doesn't know ahead of time (at compile time) what exceptions could be thrown, as a normal class method would (because of the way code dependencies are built, and because a class has to make known which exceptions it throws).

The Builder pattern uses a class that takes a request (usually via a method) and creates a new object instance based on steps (most likely defined in that class).

Conceptually a non-abstract factory, and builder are very similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
        private int i;

        public Main() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Class c = Main.class;

        try {
            c.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

In my opinion, if we use `class.newInstance()` method, we will never know the exactly exception will be thrown by the construction even though the exception is a checked exception and the checked exception isn't shown at the method signature. Just like the example above. If we use `class.newInstance()`, we will forget to handle the IOException and then get a "broken object". But the Builder pattern won't. Sorry for my pool english and hope you can understand.

Comment: That is not exactly true - neither IDE nor compiler will show any warnings/erros that indicate the constructor can throw a checked exception, but in order to use a class we need its .class file. Since we have the .class file we can always check the bytecode (or even decompile it back to Java) to determine which exceptions, if any, can be thrown by the constructor.